# Use flask to receive data from form

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to use flask to get data from a html form. The form shows up on the website ok, but when I submit python doesn't receive it.

Html code:

```
<form action="/signup" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="email"></input>
  <input type="submit" value="signup"></input>
</form>
```

Python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
@app.route('/about/')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')
@app.route('/signup', methods = ['POST'])
def signup():
    email = request.form['email']
    print("The email address is '" + email + "'")
    return redirect('/')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

APP

--static

----main.css

--templates

----html code(home.html)

python code(hello.py)

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: Where is given html code located?

Comment: will edit to show where code is located

Comment: @stamaimer there is no exception. It just doesn't print the value submitted

Comment: What should happen is the value submitted should be printed in the python console but for some reason this doesn't happen everything else works like it should. What sort of example would you like me to provide?

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine for me. 
The only thing I would change is using the `url_for()` construct instead of directly specifying your endpoints.
I.E.: use `return redirect(url_for('home'))`

Alternatively, try to provide a GET request for your 'signup' endpoint.

1. Add 'GET' to your methods argument
2. Put your printing block under an `if` statement (`if request.method == "POST"`)
3. Underneath this block put something to `return`. (`return redirect(url_for('home'))`, `return render_template('xyz.html')`, etc.)